# Синтаксический разбор сложного предложения

Tags: синтаксис, спп, ссп, сложное-предложение

Пока доехал домой посидел дома прошло еще два часа так что когда я вышел было уже светло.

Я правильно понимаю, что это предложение с неоднородным соподчинением? Здесь разные средства связи. Придаточное времени зависит от придаточного следствия.

Comment: Если вам дан хороший ответ, пожалуйста, не забудьте отметить его галочкой.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(*1.Пока доехал домой, посидел дома), [2.прошло еще два часа],(3.так что, (4.когда я вышел), было уже светло)*.

Сложноподчинённое предложение с разными видами связи - параллельным (1 времени и 3 следствия) и последовательным (3 и 4): ...прошло ещё два часа, так что было уже светло (следствия), когда я вышел(времени).

Comment: Людмила, при параллельном подчинении несколько придаточных относятся к одной главной части, но при этом отвечают на разные вопросы и/или зависят от разных слов. От какого слова в главном предложении зависит придаточное следствия?

Comment: Придаточное следствия обычно относится ко всей главной части, к грамматической основе: ...прошло 2 часа, (и что из этого следует?). Если бы это были придаточные одного типа, например времени, но относились бы к разным словам в главном предложении, подчинение было бы тоже неоднородным (параллельным.)